# What is the best practice for handling collection relationships through a REST API?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, express

This is my first question here so here it goes :)

I am developing messaging application with Android with a Node.js Express backend supported by a MongoDB database. I currently have 2 collection models: **User** and **Message** where the message schema looks like this:

```
var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  source: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
  destination: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
  text: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

My question is whether I should return a message object through the API as:

`{source: <objectId>, destination: <ObjectId>, text: 'Hello World'}`

or as:

`{source: {username:'David', password:'abcd'}, destination: {username:'Jeff', password: 'aaaa'}, text: 'Hello World'}`

In other words: **Should the referenced fields be populated/resolved on the server side, or should that be up to the client?**

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: I would recommend against passing around passwords

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment @akaphenom! You are completely right on that aspect. Right now, I am at a POC stage so the security aspect is less important for me.
In general though, I would like to know what the best practice is here, whether it's resolving the references on the server or on the client.

Comment: @Roni That depends, if the application that is using the REST API needs the source and destination data, then you should return the message with the objects populated. otherwise just return the id.

Comment: @KauêGimenes Thanks for the reply! At the moment all I really need is the source username so I am going to go with populating the source data and filtering out the destination (+ the source password).

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

`ObjectId` is an artefact of the database, not of the application.  Revealing these to the user is sometimes (not always) a smell.  Whether it is or not it down to you and your knowledge of the domain.

As far as what's best, it depends on your use cases.  Is there ever a use case where the user will only want to know the IDs?  I imagine that they'll be at least wanting one or the other.  If that's the case then I'd implement two resources, one for getting the source and one for getting the destination.

If the user will always want both, or will want both a large percentage of the time, return both or, again, add another resource that provides this.

If you do return both, what will you be filtering the set on?  An identifier of some kind, pagination or will you just be returning everything in the database?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Two things:  
1) For now I am going to go for populating the source field since my use case is displaying messages (+ their senders) to the user. 

2) On the subject of `ObjectId` being an artefact of the DB, in the case of the application needing an identifier for a user, would you recommend adding another ID field to the `User` schema?

Comment: I think in your case, where there isn't a 'natural' id then the ObjectId may well be the best bet.  there are times when it's correct and I haven't really got a hard and fast rule of when it's good and when not.